# Android - org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I have an Android application that compares the users input to the data in a MySQL database and displays it if there's a match. I'm using WAMP as a local server and PHP-files to fetch the data from the database and echo the result as JSON.

The problem is that I'm only able to search and find certain data from the database, and for some reason not all of it. It's only a problem when I try to get the data from the Android application. I'm able to get all the data that I want if I write queries directly in my DBMS. So there must be a problem with my parsing of the data but I can't figure out what it is.

Fx. I'm able to get the data if i write the following query:

```
$search_query='messi';
      $sql = 'SELECT Name, Club_position from spillere_fuld2 where MATCH(Name, Club_position) AGAINST(:search_query)';
```

But it doesn't work if I just change the name to 'ronaldo':

```
$search_query='ronaldo';
      $sql = 'SELECT Name, Club_position from spillere_fuld2 where MATCH(Name, Club_position) AGAINST(:search_query)';
```

When I do this my logcat says the following:
[image]

This is how my full PHP-file looks like:

```
<?php
 include 'config.inc.php';

 if(isset($_POST['searchQuery']))
 {
      //require_once('config.inc.php');
      $search_query=$_POST['searchQuery'];
      $search_query='messi';
      $sql = 'SELECT Name, Club_position from spillere_fuld2 where MATCH(Name, Club_position) AGAINST(:search_query)';


      $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $statement->bindParam(':search_query', $search_query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $statement->execute();
      if($statement->rowCount())
      {
    $row_all = $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($row_all);
      }  
      elseif(!$statement->rowCount())
      {
    echo "no rows";
      }
 }    
 ?>
```

This is my class where I use an AsyncTask to make the connection to the database and parse the data from JSON to Java objects:

```
    public class PlayerSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
   public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
   public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
   private RecyclerView mRVFish;
   private SearchAdapter mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_search);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    //Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.position_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
   //Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

 }

//Get string from EditText and create object of class AsyncFetch with the string.
//Need to use SearchView instead of EditText!
public void searchButton(View view){
    EditText playerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playerSearch);
    String query = String.valueOf(playerName.getText());
    new AsyncFetch(query).execute();
}

// Create class AsyncFetch
private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(PlayerSearchActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;
    String searchQuery;

    public AsyncFetch(String searchQuery) {
        this.searchQuery = searchQuery;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your php file resides
            url = new URL("http://192.168.87.100/DUFT/playersearch.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput to true as we send and recieve data
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // add parameter to our above url
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("searchQuery", searchQuery);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                //Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {
                return ("Connection error");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.dismiss();
        List<PlayerData> data = new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if (result.equals("no rows")) {
            Toast.makeText(PlayerSearchActivity.this, "No Results found for entered query", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            try {
                Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+result+"]");
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    PlayerData playerData = new PlayerData();
                    playerData.fornavn = json_data.getString("Name");
                    playerData.placering = json_data.getString("Club_position");
                    data.add(playerData);
                }

                // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                mRVFish = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
                mAdapter = new SearchAdapter(PlayerSearchActivity.this, data);
                mRVFish.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mRVFish.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(PlayerSearchActivity.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // You to understand what actually error is and handle it appropriately
                //Toast.makeText(PlayerSearchActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG", "I got an error", e);
                Toast.makeText(PlayerSearchActivity.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
}
}
```

Why am I able to get some names out of the database but not all of them?

Hope someone can help me! Thank you

Comment: the returned data is empty, try your api using postman

Comment: @OussemaAroua I don't know how to start testing my api? Can I do something else?